# Zend studio class autocompletion for classes imported by ClassRegistry init

Tags: cakephp, autocomplete, zend-studio

I am using cakephp, and if e.g. inside the component I need to use a model and I use `$myModel = ClassRegistry::init('MyModel')` trying to use some method of `$myModel` - autocomplete does not fire. When I use this way of importing models in component

```
App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');
$myModel = new MyModel();
```

autocomplete works just fine. But I am using the first method, is there a way to make it work  in that case ?

Thanks

Comment: Lot of information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585736/in-zend-studio-how-to-tell-the-ide-the-type-of-a-variable-so-i-have-auto-compl

Comment: @Holt, tks for the link, `/* @var $myModel MyModel */` worked for me, for zend studio v 10. lets post it as an answer and accept it ?